# why my flutter project keep getting error?

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, gradle

I want to use the jitsi_meet flutter package example.
https://github.com/gunschu/jitsi_meet
clone is done.
but when I run it gradle sends an error.

Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':jitsi_meet:compileDebugAidl'.

  > Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':jitsi_meet:debugCompileClasspath'.
  >   Could not resolve org.jitsi.react:jitsi-meet-sdk:2.8.0.
  >    Required by:
  >        project :jitsi_meet
  >   Could not resolve org.jitsi.react:jitsi-meet-sdk:2.8.0.
  >   Could not get resource 'https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-maven-repository/raw/master/releases/org/jitsi/react/jitsi-meet-sdk/2.8.0/jitsi-meet-sdk-2.8.0.pom'.
  >   Could not GET 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jitsi/jitsi-maven-repository/master/releases/org/jitsi/react/jitsi-meet-sdk/2.8.0/jitsi-meet-sdk-2.8.0.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 49s
Finished with error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'
}
```

}

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
```

}

Comment: have you tried ```flutter pub get``` ?

Comment: yes pub get done

Comment: have you read  README.md of this repo? make sure you are done all steps

Comment: You need to show your repositories block and your dependencies block in `build.gradle`

Comment: @AbhishekGhaskata done all steps

Comment: @smac89 add done